# Loop through dict items with keys matching a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to make this `for` and `if` in single line? I need to iterate through all the items with key starting with 'a'

```
>>> mydict
{'aName': 'Nancy', 'aAge': '25', 'bName': 'Don', 'bNumber': '21'}
>>> for k,v in mydict.items():
...    if k.startswith('a'):
...       print(k,v)
...       # do some processing here
aName Nancy
aAge 25
```

I think there should be a pythonic way to do this? something like `for k,v in mydict.items() with k.startswith('a'):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is perfectly Pythonic. It's clear, explicit, easy to read, and a pretty common/reasonable pattern that you see around software. No one will be fooled/confused by it.

To answer your question, if you really *want* a one-liner `for`/`if`, you could do:

```
for k,v in {key: value for key, value in my_dict.items() if key.startswith('a')}.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Unfortunately, this is a bit more confusing that what you already have (there's 6ish variables, including an anonymous one, instead of just 3). Another alternative is to just take this same idea (filter then iterate vs. iterate then filter), and make it two lines (for readability/semantics):

```
my_dict_startswith_a = {key: value for key, value in my_dict.items() if key.startswith('a')}
for k, v in my_dict_startswith_a.items():
    print(k,v)
```

But just stick with what you have. It looks fine.

Comment: or you use the 1-line print statement ;)

Comment: sure, I will use the 3 liner, was just wondering if it exists and I didn't know, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

```
print([k + " " + v for k, v in mydict.items() if k.startswith('a')])
```

This is called a list comprehension. This one also has a if statement in it

Answer (score 1):

Your 3 liner is fine. As for shorter: you almost had it - for loops can not have qualifiers - you either need to restict the things you for over:

```
d = {'aName': 'Nancy', 'aAge': '25', 'bName': 'Don', 'bNumber': '21'} 

# restrict the things you loop over by qualifying them as generator
for k,v in (tup for tup in d.items() if tup[0].startswith("a")):
    print(k,v)
```

or you create the print statement as one-liner using decomposition and a `sep="\n"`:

```
print( *( f"{k} {v}" for k,v in d.items() if k.startswith("a")), sep="\n")
```

Output (both cases):

```
aName Nancy
aAge 25
```

Comment: Agreed, the 3 liner is perfectly fine.